# How to run python code with spf-13.vim?

Tags: vim, spf13vim

I use [spf13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) ,it use [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) inside,but I can't find the key to run the python code.

After I add `let g:pymode_run = 1` and `let g:pymode_run_key = '<leader>r'` in my .vimrc, it still does not work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Like all distributions, spf13 adds a lot of unnecessary complexity and overhead. And it can make debugging your config quite tedious for you and anybody wishing to help. Drop that crap. Anyway, what is the output of `:verbose map <leader>r`?

Comment: @romainl oh..It maps nothing..

Answer (score 0):

oh,I got it,it maps to `,r`.I'm so careless.

Should I delete this question?